# Trouble manually sorting an array using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers

I understand this may be a simple process for some of you, but I have been working on this task for the last two weeks and have tried multiple different ways to implement a sorting procedure of an array, in a function, without passing the entire array into the function. I am only allowed to pass a pointer and the size of the array. I'm not looking for the answer to be given to me just some general tips and understanding of passing pointers into functions that control arrays. I've searched the internet and my books but most everything recommends using the premade sort function. however I have to create one myself. Below is, what i feel, the closest i've gotten to the correct code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
void ptr_sort(int *aptr, int size) ;

int main()
{
int array[5] = { 28, 87, -3, 45, 19 } ;
int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) ;
int a = array[0] ;

cout << "Original array: " ;

for(a = 0 ; a < size ; a++)
{
    cout << array[a] << " " ;
}
cout << endl ;

ptr_sort(&a, size) ;

cout << "Sorted array: " ;

for(a = 0 ; a < size ; a++)
{
    cout << array[a] << " " ;
}
cout << endl ;

return 0 ;
}


void ptr_sort(int *aptr, int size)
{
int temp ;
int b = *aptr += 1 ;

for(*aptr = 0 ; *aptr < size ; aptr++)
{
    if ( *aptr < b)
    {
        temp = *aptr ;
        *aptr = b ;
        b = temp ;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: See if you can describe in pseudocode the algorithm you hope to implement.  Your `ptr_sort()` assigns to the first element of the array as it enters the initial condition of the `for` loop, that can't be what you want.

Comment: The standard library looks at this operation as something which operates on a pair of iterators. Pointers are a special case of iterators, so you might want to look into how the standard operates on its given sequence, and what parts of its sorting algorithm it separates out into other functions. An example: there's a piece of code there that I'm certain you want to use to swap the values pointed by two pointers (it's not), a functionality which is enclosed in the standard library's [`iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap).

Comment: You seem to be confused about the behavior of pointers, as well--iteration over a range defined by a pointer, int pair is usually done with `for(int index = 0; index < size; ++index)` rather than the construct you have here, which is, for one thing, setting the first value of the array to 0. A suggestion: try to write code to sort an array of items that *aren't* capable of interacting with `int` and pointers via math operations, then change your code to operate on the requested integer values.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. Ill write out some pseudocode and then change my loops and see if I can break it down from there. I appreciate the help guys. will let you know if I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few problems in your code:

```
int main()
{
    int array[5] = { 28, 87, -3, 45, 19 } ;
    int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) ;
    int a = array[0] ;

    cout << "Original array: " ;

    for(a = 0 ; a < size ; a++)
    {
        cout << array[a] << " " ;
    }
    cout << endl ;

    ptr_sort(&a, size) ;
```

You had defined `int a` and then you assigned to it first item of your array. I guess this is not what you wanted, because at the end of code I've cited You pass pointer to `a` variable into sorting function. You probably wanted to pass pointer to array to sorting function. Also you use your `a` variable in for and you completly change its initial value.

```
void ptr_sort(int *aptr, int size)
{
int temp ;
int b = *aptr += 1 ;

for(*aptr = 0 ; *aptr < size ; aptr++)
{
    if ( *aptr < b)
    {
        temp = *aptr ;
        *aptr = b ;
        b = temp ;
    }

}
```

Here above there also a few problems:

1. `b` actually never changes, so comparing it in in for loop for sorting is a little bit pointless.
2. you use table's element as iterator in your loop. Not good.
3. your sorting algoritm seems to be bubnle sort, but lacks of one extra for loop.

Below I attach my version of your program which does a little bit better than your implementation. `ptr_sort` is not finished - as I seed you need extra `for`.
Compare it with your work and ask if You have any doubts.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
void ptr_sort(int *aptr, int size) ;

int main()
{
int array[5] = { 28, 87, -3, 45, 19 } ;
int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) ;

cout << "Original array: " ;

for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
{
    cout << array[i] << " " ;
}
cout << endl ;

ptr_sort(array, size) ;

cout << "Sorted array: " ;

for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
{
    cout << array[i] << " " ;
}
cout << endl ;

return 0 ;
}


void ptr_sort(int *aptr, int size)
{

for(int i = 0 ; i < size - 1; i++)
{
    if ( aptr[i] < aptr[i + 1] )
    {
        std::swap(aptr[i], aptr[i + 1]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I want to thank all of you. You all gave me a MUCH better understanding of arrays and pointers. Thanks for taking the time to help!